# How do I access the contents of Wordpress Classic editor in admin area with JavaScript?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, visual-editor, cms, accessibility

I am working on a small Wordpress plugin which uses JavaScript to add html tags with a css class to the visual text view in the Wordpress editor. I use the Classic Editor.

According to Chrome Developer tools, the visual text editor consists of a few div elements, and then an iframe element with the id "content_ifr" which loads a second body element which then contains all html tags pertaining to the post:

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body content post-type-post post-status-publish post-format-standard page-template-default locale-de-de mceContentBody wp-editor wp-autoresize html5-captions" data-id="content" dir="ltr" style="overflow-y: hidden;" contenteditable="true"><p>Post content</p></body>
```

I have already figured out that I can access this second body element with

```
document.getElementById("content_ifr").contentDocument.body
```

But this only works with manual input in the console, after everything has loaded. It doesn't work in the JavaScript file of the plugin which the plugin's php file loads via wp_enqueue_scripts. The corresponding variable always returns null.

How can I make the contents of the Classic editor accessible to the JavaScript file of my plugin?

Comment: Are you using the classic editor or the block editor?

Comment: are you referring to the insides of the classic editor tinymce iframe? Or are you using the block editor? It's not clear, and each has a unique answer

Comment: @TomJNowell I am using the classic editor. But I would like my plugin to work for both, so I am interested in both answers!

Comment: @JacobPeattie I edited my question to reflect your feedback.

Comment: @conpertura the answer for the block editor will be totally different from the classic editor answer, there is no overlap. Your approach might work for the classic editor, but it will not work for the block editor and will need a brand new approach from the ground up. A single solution that works for both is impossible

Comment: Can you edit your question to ask how to solve your problem rather than how to fix your solution? You do not want to know how to access the contents, you want to know how to give tables different colours. You should ask how to solve your problem, not how to implement your solution ( [you fell into the classic X Y Problem trap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140545) )

Comment: @TomJNowell I edited my question to ask only how to access the contents. The coloring of tables was intended as an example, but I can see how that might lead to confusion over the actual problem.

Comment: it's still going to require completely different solutions for classic vs block editor. There is no common solution, they're fundamentally different editors with completely different approaches. The only canonical answer to the question you asked is it is not possible using the same code. Even then, if I wrote an answer that gave you 2 separate solutions one for classic and one for the block editor, your approach would only work on the classic editor because content in the block editor is not a HTML string until it's saved, so you can modify the HTML and put it back

Comment: instead, stop using generic examples to hide what you're doing, and share your actual problem instead, then restrict your question to the block editor or the classic editor. You can always open a second question for the other. The two are not the same, and require very different solutions with very different expertise and technology

Comment: @TomJNowell Edited. I hope my question is now clear enough to receive an answer.

Comment: I've left an answer, but I will warn you, what you want this for will cause problems in the block editor and is not the right approach. The block editor already provides dedicated APIs that can help you achieve your goals but since you're hiding what you really want to do I can't guide you. E.g. block variants and HTML classes ( or maybe something else? you won't share what you really want this for, even the classic editor solution I posted below may be wrong as a result )

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you for your answer. What I want to do: I created a dedicated JavaScript program to be used as part of a website. The program selects text in content-editable divs and gives parts of it different background-colors according to certain criteriae (e. g. every table, certain words). The script makes automatic changes to the background colors when the text is edited. This is achieved by inserting or deleting html tags with a css class to display the colors. I would now like to make its functionalities accessible to the content-editable part of the Wordpress Classic Editor.

Comment: I deemed this description too complicated for a single question on StackOverflow, which is why I asked just after the situation where I got stuck. Would my above description have been better for understanding?

Comment: that would have gotten you an answer the day you asked the question, even if it was just context added to the end of the question to aid in understanding. Also, your approach will not work with the block editor and is fundamentally incompatible with it and any other editor that stores content as state rather than using the DOM itself. In TinyMCE the content and the DOM are for the most part the same thing. In the block editor, the content is stored in state and what you see is user interface, not content as DOM. To even suggest what you're hoping to do doesn't make sense in that context

Comment: instead, ask how to implement your feature, not how to implement your solution ( retrieving HTML and inserting HTML classes directly into the HTML ). You have fallen hard into the X Y problem and focused heavily on a very specific way to build it that cannot work and cannot be fixed to work in the block editor.

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you for your explanations. You seem to be experienced in the Block editor and therefore keen on highlighting the differences to the Classic Editor. I never warmed up to using the Block editor, let alone write programs for it. That's why I assumed that they were just different interfaces on the same structure / DOM, which is apparently not the case. I will take your feedback into account when asking future questions - I will state my general objective and then break it down to the part for which I need advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the editor content as a string in the classic editor use this:

```js
content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5843951/57482

Note that you should use the APIs provided rather than directly modifying the DOM if you want to modify the content. If you don't, you won't update plugins local states in javascript causing problems. Modifying the DOM should be a last resort.

Also note that this will not work for the block editor. The block editor requires a completely different approach, and you can't then edit the content and put it back without breaking the blocks or turning everything into a custom HTML block causing other issues.